# Pass two parameters with Rails/Link_to/Haml/turbo-links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, link-to, turbolinks

I'm trying to pass two parameters, `data-no-turbolinks` and `mobile`

This works:

(1)  `%a{href: "#{test_path}", data: { no: { turbolink: true }}} %span Test`

which translates to

```
<a data-no-turbolink href='/test'> <span>Test</span></a>
```

---

Now I need to add one parameter to this link: `mobile`

All of the following didn't work!

(1) `%a{href: "", mobile: 1, data: { no: { turbolink: true }}}` or

```
 %a{href: "", data: {mobile: 1, no: { turbolink: true }}}
```

(turbo-link got passed correctly, not the mobile)

(2) `%span= link_to "Mobile", {mobile: 1, data: { no: { turbolink: true }}}`

(3) `%span= link_to "Mobile", {'mobile' => 1, 'data-no-turbolink' => true }`

(4) `%span= link_to "Mobile", url_for('mobile' => 1, 'data-no-turbolink' => true)`

(5)  `%span= link_to "Mobile", data: {mobile: 1, no: {turbolink: true} }`

Comment: You need to provide the result you are getting, and what you want to get.

Comment: okay I will edit but in short, I'm trying to do this http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices  <%= link_to "Mobile Site", :mobile => 1 %> plus passing the turbolinks with it so that js gets displayed too ...

Comment: plus trying to avoid the old syntax mobile => 1 and sticking with the new syntax mobile: 1 ... althu neither is working

Answer (score 0):

```
= link_to "Mobile", '#', {"data-mobile" => "1", "data-no-turbolink" => "true"}
```

which outputs

```
<a href="#" data-no-turbolink="true" data-mobile="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) and I solve this problem using

```
ol data-no-turbolink=true #// here ol is unorders list tag for my case
```